# do specialst fields have their own colloquial vocabulary not shared by laymen?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

I saw the following passage in a PSAT study guide. One of the questions is about the use of the term 'hot spot'. Can we say it's being used colloquially and technically at the same time?
The question amounts to whether colloquial language is necessarily a part of laymen's terms.

Geologists call these volcanic areas hot spots. Lying deep in the interior of a plate, hot spots or intra-plate volcanoes are sources of magma, the red-hot, molten material within the earth's crust.

Comment: They usually refer to this as "*jargon*"

Comment: "Colloquial and technical" is quite a good description of *jargon:* an apparently informal term with a particular meaning in that particular field of study.

Comment: A word you might be thinking of is "parlance."

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: If technical jargon gets used enough in the lay media, it eventually becomes part of the general lexicon, and then it's no longer jargon.

Comment: @Apollyon: the short answer to your question ("do specialist fields have their own vocabulary not shared by laymen") is *yes* . Do you know what a "*baggywrinkle*" is? How about "*appoggiatura*"? Or "*deflocculation*"? If you were a sailor, or a pianist, or a ceramic engineer, you sure would. The very fact that we have the words "*jargon*", "*lingo*", and "*argot*" demonstrate this is an objective phenomenon.  So, if "***yes, jargon exists***", doesn't satisfy you, do you have a deeper question to ask?

Comment: @DanBron It's not my question, and you shouldn't just answer the title, you should address the points that were made in the text of the question. He referred to _hot spot_, which is a phrase that has migrated from geological jargon to colloquial English.

Comment: Sorry for the poor targetting (because of the way my browser is laid out your name appeared in the area I'd normally expect the asker's handle to appear).  But my question still stands: yes, jargon exists; what else does he want to know? (i.e., how are we to interpret "*The question amounts to whether colloquial language is necessarily a part of laymen's terms.*"?)

Comment: I suspect that 'hot spot' in the geological sense is colloquial to geology. Even if it's used by geologists, it is not their formally technical vocabulary.

Comment: Are you asking whether informal terms which are nevertheless only used by a certain technical community should be considered part of that community's jargon or the general, lay, vocabulary?

Comment: If that's the question, then I'd say the answer is still a clear "**yes**"; if you want to confine "jargon" to only those words which have precise definitions and are used in formal contexts, then you can call the larger communal vocabulary, which includes both formal and informal terms, the community's "argot", "parlance", or "lingo" (or even "slang": in the *parlance* of linguistic communities, *lingo* is *slang* for *argot*).

Answer (score 2):

"Colloquial" refers to informal, non-technical usage.

This is the opposite of the formal, technical terms utilized in scientific disciplines, such as geology.

Full Definition of COLLOQUIAL 
1
:  of or relating to conversation :  conversational 
2
a :  used in or characteristic of familiar and informal conversation; also :  unacceptably informal 
b :  using conversational style 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colloquial

JARGON
... 
2
:  the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargon